# Failing to rake on ap_geq_3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, haml

I have a remote server that has a set-up, which I can't alter, so am unable to update myself out of trouble:

Ruby is at version 1.8.7
Rubygems is at version 1.6.2
Rails is at version 2.3.4

Getting the following response when I try to rake or script/server my app both development and production versions on the server:

```
undefined method `ap_geq_3?' for Haml::Util:Module
```

I'm using capistrano and bundler, and my bundle output is:

```
    Using rake (0.8.7)
    Using activesupport (2.3.4)
    Using rack (1.0.1)
    Using actionpack (2.3.4)
    Using actionmailer (2.3.4)
    Using activerecord (2.3.4)
    Using activeresource (2.3.4)
    Using bundler (1.0.10)
    Using haml (3.1.2)
    Using mysql (2.8.1)
    Using rails (2.3.4)
    Updating .gem files in vendor/cache
```

I really don't know how to diagnose the issue further, and find the underlying conflict. Any help very much valued! Thanks.

Full trace of the error is:

```
    rake aborted!
    undefined method `ap_geq_3?' for Haml::Util:Module
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/haml-3.1.1/rails/../lib/haml/railtie.rb:1
    <--applocation-->/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    <--applocation-->/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    <--applocation-->/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    <--applocation-->/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/haml-3.1.1/rails/../lib/haml.rb:47
    <--applocation-->/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    <--applocation-->/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    <--applocation-->/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    <--applocation-->/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/haml-3.1.1/rails/../init.rb:2
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/haml-3.1.1/rails/init.rb:1:in `load'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/haml-3.1.1/rails/init.rb:1:in `evaluate_init_rb'
    <--applocation-->/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/plugin.rb:158:in `evaluate_init_rb'
    <--applocation-->/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:11:in `silence_warnings'
    <--applocation-->/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/plugin.rb:154:in `evaluate_init_rb'
    <--applocation-->/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/plugin.rb:48:in `load'
    <--applocation-->/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:38:in `load_plugins'
    <--applocation-->/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:37:in `each'
    <--applocation-->/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:37:in `load_plugins'
    <--applocation-->/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:369:in `load_plugins'
    <--applocation-->/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:165:in `process'
    <--applocation-->/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
    <--applocation-->/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
    <--applocation-->/config/environment.rb:20
    <--applocation-->/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    <--applocation-->/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    <--applocation-->/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    <--applocation-->/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    <--applocation-->/vendor/rails/railties/lib/tasks/misc.rake:4
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:607:in `invoke_prerequisites'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `each'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `invoke_prerequisites'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:596:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `run'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
    /usr/local/bin/rake:19:in `load'
    /usr/local/bin/rake:19
```